# Is there any software that uses SSDP protocol like iChat for windows 7

Tags: wireshark

Is there any software that uses SSDP protocol like iChat for windows 7.

The reason I want this  so that I can  communicate with other users on my same local area network. As I see a lot of SSDP Packets when I started sniffing my Local Area  Network for traffic to check how my network using Wireshark.

Comment: Are you sure iChat uses SSDP, and not DNS-SD?

Comment: Thats what i found when i did a google search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want SSDP you can try [Miranda IM](http://www.miranda-im.org/) or [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/).